# Form not submitted on Window

Tags: extjs

I create a Window with a form in it with this code:

```
    var confirm = new Ext.Window({
                      //xtype: 'form',
                      hidden: true,
                      id: 'FrmModalWindow',
                      autodestroy: true,
                      layout: 'auto',
                      bodyPadding: 10,
                      items: [
                        //
                        {xtype: 'form',
                        id: 'FrmModalConfirma',
                         autodestroy: true,
                        layout: 'auto',
                        bodyPadding: 10,
                        items: [
                          {
                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Esta seguro que desea guardar los cambios y recalcular la categoría?',
                            labelWidth: 500
                          },
                          {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            width: 500,
                            name: 'id_motivo_modificacion',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            fieldLabel: 'Motivo de los cambios',
                            labelWidth: 150,
                            store: 'MotivoStore',
                            displayField: 'descripcion_motivo_modificacion',
                            valueField: 'id_motivo_modificacion'

                          },
                          {
                            xtype: 'textareafield',
                            width: 500,
                            name: 'observacion',
                            fieldLabel: 'Observaciones',
                            labelWidth: 150
                          },
                          {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            anchor: '100%',
                            itemId: 'hiddenFieldCedulaGeneral',
                            fieldLabel: 'Label',
                            name: 'cedula_estudiante',
                            hidden: true,
                            emptyText: cedulaGeneral.getValue()
                          },
                          {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            anchor: '100%',
                            itemId: 'hiddenFieldEstado',
                            fieldLabel: 'Label',
                            name: 'cod_estado',
                            hidden: true,
                            emptyText: 'MPA'
                          },
                          {
                          xtype: 'container',
                          layout: 'column',
                          items: [
                            {
                              xtype: 'button',
                              text: 'Si, recalcular',
                              listeners: {
                                click: function(){

        /*********************************************
        ************* SUBMIT THE FORM ****************
        *********************************************/

        var formaGeneral = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#FrmModalConfirma")[0];
        console.log(formaGeneral);
        if(formaGeneral.isValid()){
          formaGeneral.submit(
            {
              url: '../servidor/sbs/informaciongeneral/duplicaultimoingreso',
              success: function(response, opts){
                console.log("Se duplicó con éxito");
              },
              failure: function(response,opts){
                console.log("Error al duplicar");
              }
            });
        }

        /********************************************
        ************** DO A LOT OF OTHER STUFF ******
        ********************************************/



                                //CLOSE AFTER SAVING
                                  var ventana = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#FrmModalWindow")[0];
                                  ventana.destroy();
/************************************************
If I change ventana.destroy() to ventana.hide(), the form does submit
*************************************************/
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              xtype: 'tbspacer',
                              width: 30
                            },
                            {
                              xtype: 'button',
                              text: 'No, cancelar',
                              listeners: {
                                click: function(){
                                  //Cierra la ventana
                                  var ventana = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#FrmModalWindow")[0];
                                  ventana.destroy();
/************************************************
If I change ventana.destroy() to ventana.hide(), the form does submit
*************************************************/
                                }
                              }
                            }
                        ]
                        }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    });

    confirm.show();
```

So if I leave the code as ventana.destroy(), the form created never gets submitted, if I change it to ventana.hide() the form does get submitted but it creates several copies of the window if the user keeps using the option that calls that window. I don't understand why the form isn't found when using ventana.destroy();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The submit call is async, if you destroy it straight away it never hits the server.

What you could do is hide the form immediately, then destroy it in the success/failure callback.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the issue